# Why does Make ignore my wildcard rule?

Tags: makefile

Why doesn't Make link to `foo.o`?

```
$ ls
foo.c  foo_test.c  Makefile

$ cat Makefile 
.PHONY: test
test: foo_test
%_test: %_test.o foo.o

$ make
cc     foo_test.c   -o foo_test
```

Comment: Make has a predefined rule to make `foo.o` from `foo.c`. The strange thing is that if I change the rule to `foo_test: foo_test.o foo.o` then `cc` will link with `foo.o`.

Comment: I don't understand why this is happening, but I notice that if you change the pattern rule from a rule with no commands to a rule with an empty command (`%_test: %_test.o foo.o ;`) then the rule works as intended.

Comment: @Beta: That doesn't work for me. With the empty command both foo_test.c and foo.c are compiled but no linking takes place. I run GNU Make 3.81. What version of Make do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think you were using "link" in a precise sense. Let me try to compose an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern rules MUST have a recipe associated with them.  Any pattern rule without a recipe tells GNU make to delete that pattern rule.  So, your line:

```
%_test: %_test.o foo.o
```

does nothing except delete the non-existent pattern rule to build `%_test` from `%_test.o`.  You need to create a recipe if you want it to take effect:

```
%_test: %_test.o foo.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $(LIBS) $^
```

or whatever.  However, this is completely not necessary for your example.  You don't need any rule at all for that, just write:

```
foo_test: foo_test.o foo.o
```

and let make's built-in rules handle it.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. My example was a simplification of a larger and more complex makefile so I can't really simplify it like you suggest.

Comment: PS: I disagree about "...tells GNU Make to delete that pattern rule", but it's a subtle point that doesn't change the final answer.

Comment: This seems to be my month for misreading things. Somehow I read your statement as "tells Make to delete whatever rule may already exist for that pattern", rather than "will be ignored".